# jQuery loop and store PHP values into array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, google-visualization

**PHP array output $color_str**

```
Array
(
    [0] => '#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'
    [1] => '#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [2] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [3] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [4] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [5] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [6] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
    [7] => '#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'
)
```

**JSON encode**

```
["'#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'","'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'","'#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'"]
```

$color_string = json_encode($color_str);

**Script**

```
var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 300,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            bar: {groupWidth: '50%'},
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {title: "Resource(s)"},
            vAxis: {title: "Week(s)"},
        colors: resColorsStr(),
        };


function resColorsStr(){
    var color_str = [];
    for(c = 0; c <= 7 ; c++){
        color_str = [<?php echo $color_string [c] ?>];
        //color_str.push(<?php echo $color_string [c]?>);

    }
    console.log(color_str);
    return color_str;

}
```

How do I loop and store array values into `color_str`, so for first loop `color_str  = '#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'`, for second
`color_str  = '#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'`

Thus, when the function `resColorsStr` is called, it will display colors likewise.

Comment: Are you storing the entire php array in a js variable anywhere? Due to php being server side, you may need to put the entire for loop in php instead of just the single echo.

Comment: just `json_encode(array([0] => '#4caf50',...)` and parse it client side

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Please see my updated question.

Comment: because you have string not an array, `"'#4caf50','...,'#00bcd4'"` can you see the double quote here see this http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ia9zS3

Comment: @NullPoiиteя ,Being a newbie, what am I now supposed to do ? Could you pls elaborate

Comment: sorry your question is quite subjective i can not help further

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, with given array the resulting output after json_encode would be `["'#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'",`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In PHP:

```
$color_string = json_encode($color_str);
```

In javascript:

```
json = JSON.parse('<?=$color_string?>');
```

And then in options variable:

```
var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 300,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            bar: {groupWidth: '50%'},
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {title: "Resource(s)"},
            vAxis: {title: "Week(s)"},
        colors: json,
        };
```

I've not tested it but it should work.

Comment: `$color_string` would be `["'#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'","'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50'"]`. Using above snippet it will throw exception like `SyntaxError: illegal character
 

var json = JSON.parse('["'#4caf50','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'","'#0...`